# Making a list out of an index from a datetime

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, bokeh

**Main Question:** I set the df index doing this: `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')` which gives me this:

```
print df.index
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-07-28 09:42:08, ..., 2015-07-28 09:06:12]
Length: 15177, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

I want a list of the month and years in order to use them to plot, like so: `["Jan 2015", "Feb 2015", "Mar 2015", "Apr 2015", "May 2015", "June 2015", "Jul 2015", "Aug 2014", "Sep 2014", "Oct 2014", "Nov 2014", "Dec 2014"]`

**Background:** I am taking a year's worth of data and making a graph using Bokeh. The y-axis is the month, the x axis is the CompanyName. I want to add the year to the month, though this will dynamically change so I don't want to do it manually the way I did the months.

```
df = pd.read_csv('MYDATA.csv')
df['recvd_dttm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['recvd_dttm'])

#Only retrieve data before now (ignore typos that are future dates)
mask = df['recvd_dttm'] <= datetime.datetime.now()
df = df.loc[mask]
# get first and last datetime for final week of data

range_max = df['recvd_dttm'].max()
range_min = range_max - pd.DateOffset(years=1)

# take slice with final week of data
df = df[(df['recvd_dttm'] >= range_min) & 
               (df['recvd_dttm'] <= range_max)]
df = df.set_index('recvd_dttm')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

Then I have code to pull the required data and format it into a pivot table for graphing. Next, I make the figure:

```
MonthNames = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
p = figure(title="Customer Calls for blank in Last Year", 
    x_range=Companies, y_range=MonthNames,
    x_axis_location="above", plot_width=1200, plot_height=900,
    toolbar_location="left", tools=TOOLS)
```

I want `["Jan 2015", "Feb 2015", "Mar 2015", "Apr 2015", "May 2015", "June 2015", "Jul 2015", "Aug 2014", "Sep 2014", "Oct 2014", "Nov 2014", "Dec 2014"]`
I tried to use + '%Y' to concatenate on to the y_range but I got `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`

I'm pretty sure the solution is to take the df.index and put it into a list, then cut out repeats and add it onto the y_range. 
I tried to do `date_list = [set(df.index.year)]` but this obviously gives `[{2014, 2015}]` which is not helpful.

I'm not sure how to do this, does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
[dt.datetime.strftime(n,'%b-%Y') for n in pd.DataFrame(yourdataframe).resample('M').index]
```

I think it should return a list of datetimes formatted as you're looking for.

It takes your index, re-indexes it to 'M' monthly (other options are available, e.g. A=annually, Q=quarterly etc)
Then iterates through the results, converting them using the dt.datetime.strftime function to get to the format you're after.
Finally, it all gets wrapped up into a list as a result of being part of a list-comprehension.

Comment: I'm getting different errors depending on where I try to put it. One is TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex When I try to do this after setting the index and converting it to_datetime. The other is DataError: No numeric types to aggregate, If I use it after taking my slice of data without setting the index.

Comment: Aha ok, sometimes the resample thing can get tricky if your dataframe has data that doesn't aggregate well - you could try constructing a new dataframe using only your index from the original one - maybe something like    `q = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([n for n in range(0,len(yourframe.index))],index=yourframe.index)).resample('M').index` which should create a DataFrame q, that you can then iterate through the strftime function `[dt.datetime.strftime(n,'%b-%Y') for n in q]` - is that any better?